# Que significa o «t» em (apartamento) t0, t1, t2, t3?

Tags: significado, etimologia

Creio que isto é uma coisa só de Portugal. T0 (t-zero), t1, t2, etc. são apartamentos. Um *t**n*** tem ***n*** **+ 1** divisões além da cozinha, casas de banho, despensa. O apartamento mais básico é o t0 que tem só uma sala que também serve de quarto de dormir; um t1 tem uma sala mais um quarto; e assim por diante.

Entretanto também se começou a ver v1, v2, etc. para designar vivendas. O ***v*** vem com certeza da inicial de *vivenda*. Mas donde vem o ***t***? 
Fiz uma busca rápida na net, e nalguns foruns diz-se que ***t*** significa *tipo*, mas ninguém cita fontes credíveis. Creio que isto é uma terminologia recente. Coisa de duas, três décadas?

Portanto o que eu quero saber é o que significa o ***t*** e, se possível, onde e quando é que esta terminologia começou a ser usada.

Comment: Aparte: um _t**n**_ tem **_n_ + 1** assoalhadas.

Comment: @JNat Exato. Mas a explicação é sobretudo para os brasileiros, e parece-me que *assoalhada* também não se usa por lá.

Comment: Sim, sim: não estava a querer corrigir. Só a chegar à conclusão de que, independentemente do que seja o "t", nem sequer corresponde ao número de assoalhadas, mas sempre a esse número -1.

Comment: Bem, a bounty era para recompensar uma resposta existente. Mas devo ter feito uma trapalhice qualquer, e tenho de esperar 23 horas. Mas pronto, se alguém conseguir melhorar...

Comment: Há uns 40 anos tive essa dúvida e alguém me disse que queria dizer "tacos", uma trapalhada que se tornou moda.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Encontrei [nesse blogue](http://intelectuais.blogspot.pt/2011/11/afinal-o-que-e-o-t.html)¹ que a origem da designação *Tx* pode ter sido do **"Regulamento Geral das Edificações Urbanas de 1951"** que o autor não conseguiu encontrar.

Fiz uma pesquisa aprofundada no site [Diário da República Eletrónico](https://dre.pt) e encontrei o [Decreto-Lei n.º 38382 de 1951](https://dre.pt/web/guest/pesquisa/-/search/289214/details/normal?q=1951-08-07) que aprova o **"Regulamento Geral das Edificações Urbanas de 1951"** e não encontrei nenhuma referência nem a *tipo*, nem a *tipologia* e nem a *Tx*.

No entanto, ao pesquisar as alterações feitas a esse Regulamento, encontrei o [Decreto-Lei n.º 650/75 de 1975](https://dre.pt/web/guest/pesquisa/-/search/310259/details/normal?l=1) que, e passo a citar,

> Dá nova redacção a diversos artigos do Regulamento Geral das
>   Edificações Urbanas, aprovado pelo Decreto-Lei n.º 38382, de 7 de
>   Agosto de 1951

Esta nova redação inclui, pela primeira vez, uma referência a *Tx* que é definido como sendo *tipo de fogo*:

[image]

Curiosamente a [Portaria n.º 676/79 de 1979](https://dre.pt/web/guest/pesquisa/-/search/366431/details/normal?q=Portaria%20676%20de%201979), que encontrei por acaso, já faz referência a tipologia, embora também faça referência ao ponto 5 enunciado anteriormente:

[image]

O que faz parecer é que é só preferência de uso de *tipologia* em vez de *tipo*, tendência que o [Projeto de Decreto-Lei de janeiro de 2007](https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/3779571328643/) parece confirmar:

[image]

---

<sup>1 - Ao que parece, atualmente, este blogue está aberto apenas a leitores convidados</sup>

---

Fica também uma curiosidade tirada do [ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/fogo-habitacao-origem/7588) sobre a origem de fogo (habitação):

> Antigamente, quando ainda nem sequer havia fogões, onde ardesse a lenha para preparar as refeições, cada habitação tinha a cozinha onde, numa fornalha ou na lareira, ardia a lenha para preparar os alimentos. Essa lareira era, nalgumas casas, junto à parede e noutras no canto da cozinha. No inverno, as famílias, tantas vezes acompanhada pelos vizinhos, recebiam à noite o calor agradável daquele «fogo» tão necessário para o seu aquecimento. Era esse «fogo» de tanto valor para aquela gente, que a palavra «fogo» se sobrepôs a **moradia, casa, habitação, residência, etc..** E assim, passaram a dizer-se frases como esta: A minha aldeia é a maior daquela região, tem oitenta «fogos». Compreende-se, porque aquele «fogo» era, no inverno, o centro, a alma da convivência amigável daquelas pessoas que muito se queriam.

Comment: Bravo. Esta é possivelmente a origem. Nota que no documento se usa *tipo*, e que não aparece uma única vez *tipologia*, que sempre me pareceu inflação palavrosa. Seria como as lojas afixarem a preçologia em vez dos preços dos produtos. Parece-me que  estes ts só entraram na linguagem corrente bem mais tarde.

Comment: @Jacinto é tens razão, eu nas minhas pesquisas em documentos não encontrei nenhuma referencia a *tipologia*, foi mais fácil pesquisar por *fogo*, isto depois de descobrir que fogo é sinonimo de habitação.

Comment: Encontrei os ts num artigo do Público de 1991: Os preços das habitações variam dos 18 mil contos de um T1 35 mil contos para os T2, 50 mil contos para os T3 até aos 100 mil contos dos T6. As características que levam à definição de empreendimento de qualidade são os pavimentos em carvalho francês, cozinhas, zonas de serviço e casas de banho em mármore, caixilharia em alumínio lacado e vidros duplos, aquecimento individual, videofone e canalizações para gás natural. Além das habitações, o empreendimento conta ainda com dez lojas e 220 lugares para estacionamento, piscina e health club.

Comment: Um voto negativo!? É raro uma resposta conseguir determinar a origem de uma expressão com tanta exatidão e segurança!

Comment: Excelente. A linguagem da lei é curiosa. Diz que é Tx em que x é número de quartos de dormir, o que permitiria pensar que um apartamento com 3 quartos e duas salas seria um T3; mas é um T4, como toda a gente em Portugal sabe. A questão é que a lei presume que um apartamento tem cozinha e uma única sala, e que tudo resto são quartos de dormir (ver quadro do [artigo 66](https://dre.pt/application/conteudo/310259)); >>

Comment: O projeto de lei de 2007 é mais explícito: "Para efeitos de aplicação do presente regime, consideram-se com a designação de quartos todos os compartimentos habitáveis, para além **da sala** e da cozinha" (negrito meu).

Comment: @Jacinto tens de dar um desconto, em 1975 não devia ser muito habitual teres 2 salas ;)

Comment: A casa dos meus tios no Cacém tinha uma sala de estar e uma de jantar separada (mas quase sempre comíamos na cozinha). E era de ver que é o morador que decide o que é que cada compartimento vai ser. Se o x do Tx fosse simplesmente o número de assoalhadas seria muito mais lógico. Era assim aliás que eram (e ainda são) descritas casas 3 assoalhadas, 4 assoalhadas, etc. Às tantas eles queriam mesmo começar em T0.

Answer (score 3):

O `T` de «T1» significa tipologia.

Isto é confirmável com uma pesquisa *online* por «tipologia T0», que retorna muitos resultados que confirmam este significado dentro do dialeto imobiliário.

Comment: Fonte: "toda a gente sabe".

Comment: «Tipologia t0» dá melhores resultados («t0 tipologia» vem quase só de um único site). Então e quando e é que isto começou e quem é que começou? Não me descobres isso? Será que veio de Espanha? Também aparece nuns sites em espanhol.

Comment: Bah, sei lá quando. Isso dá trabalho a encontrar.

Comment: @Jacinto não vi isso quando vivia na Espanha.  Se for que antes o usavam, pois já não é comum.

Comment: significa tipologia sim, mas são o numéro de quartos: https://ana-macao-kw.pt/tipologias-de-habitacao T1, T2, T2 1 quarto, dois quartos, etc. Não se pode copiar nada do site.

Answer (score -1):

Sim, como foi dito pelo ANeves. O link abaixo confirma que T significa quarto.

> A tipologia de uma habitação
>
> É uma fórmula usada para designar o número de quartos assoalhados de
>   uma casa. Ou seja, assoalhada é a designação para uma divisão usada
>   para dormir, cujo chão habitualmente possuía soalho de madeira. Daí
>   que as restantes divisões: salas, cozinhas, casas de banho, espaços de
>   arrumo, **não contém para efeitos da designação T.
>   **
>
> As tipologias podem ser:
>
> T1 (1 quarto), T2 (2 quartos), T3 (3 quartos), T4 (4 quartos), T5 (5
>   quartos), etc.
>
> Também pode ser encontrada a designação de T2+1, sendo que o +1 serve
>   para indicar mais uma divisão (que pode ser a sala ou um sótão
>   convertido en mais uma divisão).

[tipo de habitação](https://www.aransa.pt/tipo-de-habitacoes/)

Comment: Viste a resposta do Jorge? Ela já já inclui a reprodução da parte relevante do Regulamento Geral das Edificações Urbanas de 1951, que criou a nomenclatura T0, T1, etc. e mostra que o T vem de "tipo" ("tipologia" na revisão de 2007 desse regulamento). Não vejo o que é que a tua resposta acrescenta.

Comment: É so uma fonte mais. Não é permitido? Ele não citou o que eu citei exatamente...